# Generate Tree List upto certain level only in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, tree

I am trying to populate a select box from a Category table with Tree Behavior.

> $categories =
>   $this->Category->generateTreeList(null,null,null,'   ');

This lists all the categories. As the tree is upto 5 level deep, the select box gets populated massively.

Is there a way to limit the number of levels to generate so that I don't need to display all tree data ? I would like to display upto 3rd level only.

*I am using CakePHP 2.3.5.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null,'   ', 3);
```

According to the docs for [generateTreeList()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior::generateTreeList) there is a fith parameter for levels deep.

**generateTreeList($conditions=null, $keyPath=null, $valuePath=null, $spacer= '_', $recursive=null)**

Parameters:
 
  $conditions – Uses the same conditional options as find().
  $keyPath – Path to the field to use for the key.
  $valuePath – Path to the field to use for the label.
  $spacer – The string to use in front of each item to indicate depth.
  $recursive – The number of levels deep to fetch associated records

Comment: The recursive parameter is not filtering the level. It just populates the depth of information to be shown, not the actual tree depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-TreePlus/blob/master/Model/Behavior/TreePlusBehavior.php) behavior which stores the depth/level of each node when it's created/updated. Then when fetching records using generateTreeList() you can just specify the depth in conditions.